# Visual Studio 2013 Get Latest Version not working

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I have a problem whenever I check in something in my TFS collection and try to `Get Latest Version(Recursive)` on other machines the changes not taking place and I get a message that I already have the latest version until I use `Get Specified Version` and then `Overwrite all files even if the local version matches the specified version`
I am using (Visual Studio 2013 update 3 and Visual Studio 2012 update 4) with TFS 2013 update 2

Comment: what type is your workspace? server or local

Comment: my workspace is local

Comment: do you have any files locked/checked out on the machine that isn't getting latest properly?  By default a get latest will not override files that are currently being edited on that workspace.

Comment: no files were checked out or edited on the machine that I want to get the latest version.

Comment: Where are you doing this from?  Solution Explorer?  Source Control Explorer?

Comment: so this is happening across multiple machines?

Comment: This problem usually only occurs when using server based workspaces. Can you check if you have multiple workspaces on your 'other machine' and confirm which one is being used?

Comment: I have only one workspace on the current PC that I perform get latest version.